# xml node value update not working

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to update my XML file node with post variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<paypal>
    <received>0</received>
</paypal>
```

PHP:

```
$paypal = simplexml_load_file("paypal.xml");
    $paypal->received = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $paypal->asXML("paypal.xml");
```

But no changes in file appear.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions for `paypal.xml`?

Comment: you should NEVER use posted input directly, without sanitizing it first. "injection attacks" is the general keyword and i think, it even applies to xml: http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13247004/XML%20Injection

Comment: @Creadiff: You know what... that might be the reason. Will check it out, it's GoDaddy's account that I use. Do you find it weird??

Answer (score 0):

Change for: `$paypal->received[0] = $_POST['mc_gross'];` as mentioned on php.net @ http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php#107409

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it might be permission issue more than anything, as it seems to me that first array element is set by default. And this is not working as well.